# Does it make sense to take out the cake from the oven few times just to check whether it is done or not?

Tags: baking, cake

Does it make sense to take out the cake from the oven few times just to check whether it is done or not, before its total time completes?

Is there some other way out to check the same, in order to avoid a miserable failure at the end?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's never the best of an idea taking the cake out of the oven during its cooking as you'll probably knock it a bit and knock the air out and then it'll cool down a bit and so take longer too cook. Saying that, the whole thing is when you take the cake out. As a rule don't take your cake out until at least half-way through the cooking time, that way the starch will have started to set. If you take your cake out multiple times 5 minutes before, say, it don't make to much of a difference as by then the cake is practically cooked.

Some cakes are more susceptible: foam cakes (genoise, chiffon, etc) are the most likely to feel the full force of you taking the cake out of the oven as it will likely deflate all of the air you've worked so hard to create, however, butter cakes (pound, fruit, etc) wil not be so effected as these are a lot denser and rely more on chemical leaveners.

There are lots of ways to check if your cakes done. If its a cake with quite a thin batter, open the oven door and give it a tiny wobble (not a great big shake to deflate it) and if it wobbles its definitely not done, if it doesn't wobble you can progress to the next step which is poking in a skewer or knife and if it comes out clean it's done, use this technique for all cake types. Another way is when the cake looks golden (unless it's a chocolate cake), press your finger down on the cake and if it springs back it's done. A lot is made about not opening your oven door, in modern ovens today, this doesn't make much of a difference as they can quickly get back up to temperature, particularly if you just open the door a crack. On a final point having a reliable oven temperature is one of the most important steps. Buying a little oven thermometer is a good investment, they're very cheap and will save a lot of hastle

Comment: Another thing to look for is whether the cake 'shrinks', letting loose from the walls. Then it's surely done as well.

Comment: Upvote for thoughtful answer.